# find regex with date range in filename

Tags: regex, gnu-findutils

I've files in a folder like

```
file_2017-01-01.jpg    
file_2017-02-20.jpg    
file_2017-05-10.jpg    
file_2017-09-01-jpg    
file_2017-10-25.jpg    
file_2017-11-04.jpg    
file_2017-12-22.jpg
```

How can I use the find command to list files from `file_2017-01*` to `file_2017-10*` ?

`find  . -regextype posix-awk -regex  ".*2017-[01-10]*"` doesn't work.

Also not, `find  . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*2017-[01-10]*"`

Comment: `[x-y]` is a character class. It matches only one character at a time.

Comment: and btw, this isn't a bash question -- the `find` command (at least, the version that supports `-regextype`) is part of GNU `findutils`, which is a completely separate and unrelated package from bash.

Answer (score 0):

A character class only matches one character at a time, so on its own, it's not an adequate tool for the job in question. Consider instead:

```
find  . -regextype posix-awk -regex '.*_2017-(0[1-9]|10)-.*' -print
```

This has two branches: `0[1-9]`, matching any two-character string from 01 through 09; and `10`, matching only the exact string `10`.

Comment: ...btw, I'll flag this community-wiki as soon as the question gets its dupe flag set. (Removing the bash tag deactivated my dupehammer... oops!)